# Sobolev space membership of logarithmic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Determine the largest $s\in(0,1)$ for which the following integral converges
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\Big|\log|x-\frac{1}{2}|-\log|y-\frac{1}{2}|\Big|}{|x-y|^{1+2s}}^{2}dxdy$$